# How to get Contatcs id in phone contacts but iam getting row id in android

Tags: android

Iam reading all information in phone contacts but how to get contact unique id.

public List getPhoneContacts(ContentResolver cr) {
        ArrayList phoneContactsList = new ArrayList();

```
    Cursor phone = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, null,
            null, null);

    while (phone.moveToNext()) {
        phoneContactID = -101;



        phoneContactID = phone.getInt(phone
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));


        name = phone
                .getString(phone
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        phoneNumber = phone
                .getString(phone
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        email = phone
                .getString(phone
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        if (phoneContactID != -101) {
            PhoneContactsPojo phoneContact = new PhoneContactsPojo();
            phoneContact.setID(phoneContactID);
            phoneContact.setName(name);
            phoneContact.setNumber(phoneNumber);
            phoneContact.setEmail(email);
            phoneContactsList.add(phoneContact);
        }

    }
    phone.close();
    return phoneContactsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi use simple contact pick for get all the contacts ,check this sample code,

onCreate(Bundel save)
{
        /** Call the Contacts Picker */
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
            finish();
        }else
        {
            Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID;
            String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

            switch (requestCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT) :

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri contactData = data.getData();//getting user selected data from contacts picker
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contactData, null,null, null, null); //loading selected values in cursor
            // Loop for every contact in the phone
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));//Contact id 
                    contact_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));// Contact name



                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);


                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));

                        if(Globals.currentapiVersion >= Globals.targetVesrion) {
                            String img_uri = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

                            if(img_uri != null){
                                mContactsModel.contact_image_path = img_uri;

                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            long val = Long.parseLong(contact_id);
                            Uri img_uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, val);

                            if(img_uri != null){
                                mContactsModel.contact_image_path = ""+img_uri;

                            }
                        }

                        if(mContactsModel.contact_image_path != null && mContactsModel.contact_image_path.length()>0)
                        {

                            contact_imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mContactsModel.contact_image_path));

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            contact_imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_person_contact); 
                        }
                        //showLog("phoneNumber ",phoneNumber);
                    }
                    displayAdapter();
                    phoneCursor.close();

                }
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                showAlertDialog(getString(R.string.no_phone_number_for_this_contact),getString(R.string.phone_book),getString(R.string.cancel),0);
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void getListContacts(Activity activity,List<Contacts> contacts_list){

             String phone = "";
            ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if(cur.getCount()>0){
                cur.moveToFirst();
                while (!cur.isAfterLast()){
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String image_uri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                    if(Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))>0)
                    {
                         Cursor cursorPhone =activity. getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,

                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?" ,

                                    new String[]{id},
                                    null);
                        while (cursorPhone.moveToNext()) { 
                            phone = cursorPhone .getString(cursorPhone .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                                Contacts contacts=new Contacts();
                                contacts.setContact_id(id);
                                contacts.setContact_name(name);
                                contacts.setMy_image(image_uri);
                                //System.out.println("contact number "+ phone);
                                //System.out.println("contact number "+ phone.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", ""));
                                contacts.setContact_number(phone.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", ""));
                                contacts_list.add(contacts);

                        }
                        cursorPhone.close();

                    }
                    else{
                        phone="Not Valid";
                    }

                    cur.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In this case my problem is solve but actual problem is not get contact id iam get row id of each contact.

Comment: Work this code well, My problem is using id to show profile whenever save same mobile number in phone contacts click one contact get different profile.How to solve it.

Comment: what you want to do with this id ? You already have all profile information.